# Jacoco code coverage report shows wrong coverage

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco

I have integrated Jacoco to a maven project.

When computing coverage for a particular class, the report shows code coverage percentage for each method in that class as close to 40% - 50% even though the coverage is 100%. This is the case with multiple other java classes as well.

Any idea as to why this happens? Appreciate your help to solve this.

Comment: Even I have same issue. Were you able to fix this?

Comment: I also have the same issue. pl update whenever it gets solved